# SQLite SELECT all for Last 7 days

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I can't return the last seven days in my sql query it only returns records from the previous month of the current month does not return records.
Below my query works, but not as I wanted it only brings a record of the previous month of the current month does not bring the records.

```
SELECT * FROM processos where dt_alteracao > (select strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', 'now' , '-7 days'));
```

[Image of query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhGBc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column has the format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` then you can do it with the function `datetime()`:

```
SELECT * FROM processos 
where dt_alteracao > datetime('now' , '-7 days');
```

Comment: The problem was that the data format saved in the field was not in the datatime standard.

Comment: @gomes remember that for SQLite the only valid text datetime format is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. All the datetime functions that SQLite supports work only with this format.